# Adaptive Drop Down Menu with PHP functions Populating from a MySQL server

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

I have three drop down menus that I have been trying to make dependent on one another so that once a selection has been made in the first drop down, the options for the second one will change. Then once a selection has been made in the second drop down menu, the third dropdown menu will change. My HTML looks like this:

```
<select class = "homepageSelectors , hpSelectorMenu" id = "classSelector" name="classSelector" >
    <option selected="selected">Select</option>
    <option value= "geometry">Geometry</option>
    <option value= "english1">English 1</option>
    <option value= "algebra2">Algebra 2</option>
</select>

<select class = "homepageSelectors , hpSelectorMenu" id = "levelSelector" name="levelSelector">

</select>

<select class = "homepageSelectors , hpSelectorMenu" id = "teacherSelector" name="teacherSelector">

</select>
```

---

The first drop down is hard coded because the options will not change. Although, what I need to do is when the first one is changed, run a PHP function to query an SQL database and get the options for the second dropdown menu. I have the following jquery code in another file that runs a function when the first dropdown is changed.

```
$("#classSelector").change( function () {
    //In here is where I need to run a PHP function
});
```

---

I realize that I can call an external PHP file from in that jquery function, although my problem is that once I query my SQL server from that external PHP file, I have no way of returning the results from the query to my HTML file so that the second drop down menu can be populated.

I have been looking at other forums trying to find a solution, although I was unable to find any posts similar to my scenario. I am not too familiar with ajax, but if you think that it is the way to do it, please do explain. THANKS FOR ALL THE HELP!!!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [jQuery Ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

Make a request the .php file in order to get the data you want. A way simple example to get you an idea:

Your javascript function file:

```
$("#classSelector").change( function () {
    //In here is where I need to run a PHP function

    var value = $(this).val();
    // load data if value is different than 'selected'
    if(value != 'selected') {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'your_file.php',
            data: {classID: $(this).val()},
            dataType: 'html',
            type: "GET",
            success: function(data) {
                // drop the output in #levelSelector select
                $('select#levelSelector').html(data);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

This can be translate to something like your_file.php?classID=Geometry for example:

Your php file:

```
<?php

// This is an example your php script should output what you need 
// and how you need even if loading data from SQL Server / MySQL etc...

$classID = (isset($_GET['classID'])) ? $_GET['classID'] : null;

switch($classID)
{
    case 'Geometry':
    echo "<option value='level1'>Level 1</option>";
        break;
    default:
    break;
}

// Output
<option value='level1'>Level 1</option>
```

The output will be inside the '#levelSelector' select and like this:

```
<select class = "homepageSelectors , hpSelectorMenu" id = "levelSelector" name="levelSelector">
    <option value='level1'>Level 1</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

So, I think what you're really asking for here is: how do I use JavaScript and PHP to live-query a database?

There are two parts to this. The JavaScript script and the PHP script. JavaScript will make an AJAX call to the PHP script, which will then query the database and return the results of that query to the JavaScript that made the initial request.

It seems you are already using jQuery, so that's great, since jQuery has a really useful feature for making network calls: [`$.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

Taking the code you already have and expanding it:

```
$("#classSelector").change( function () {
  var selectedClass = $(this).find(":selected").text();

  $.ajax({
    url: '/path/to/class/select/php/script.php',
    data: {selectedValue: selectedClass}, // Send this data to the PHP script
    dataType: 'json', // Let's assume the PHP script will send us a JSON response
    success: function(data) { // Gets called if the entire request is successful
      console.log('Server returned level options for class ' + selectedClass, data);
      // data now contains the array of options for levelSelector.
      // I'm going to assume you know how to loop through them and populate levelSelector
    }
  });
});
```

We need the exact same code for `levelSelector`, just changing two little things:

```
$("#levelSelector").change( function () {
  var selectedLevel = $(this).find(":selected").text();

  $.ajax({
    url: '/path/to/level/select/php/script.php',
    data: {selectedValue: selectedLevel}, // Send this data to the PHP script
    dataType: 'json', // Let's assume the PHP script will send us a JSON response
    success: function(data) { // Gets called if the entire request is successful
      console.log('Server returned teacher options for class ' + $("#classSelector").find(":selected").text() + 'and  level ' + selectedLevel, data);
      // data now contains the array of options for teacherSelector.
      // I'm going to assume you know how to loop through them and populate teacherSelector
    }
  });
});
```

Cool. Now, let's get one of our PHP scripts setup. I'm going to assume you are using a MySQL database, and for this example I am not going to include any of the code you need to use to cleans and secure the script (you can find that all over other questions on SO). Most of the PHP script is a straight [copy/paste from W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select.asp).

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: application/json'); // We are going to send a JSON response

// Server connection info
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "myDB";

$selectedValue = $_REQUEST['selectedValue'];

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
  die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "SELECT * FROM levels WHERE class = " . $selectedValue; // THIS IS AN EXAMPLE. IN PRODUCTION, ALWAYS CLEAN USER INPUT FIRST.
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
  // output data of each row
  $results = array();
  while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $results[] = $row;          
  }

  echo json_encode($results);
} else {
  echo json_encode("0 results");
}

$conn->close();
```